# Boolean on List gives erratic results

Tags: c#, list, boolean, compare

I have this line of code:

```
bool existsbuy = pricelist.Exists(element => (element <= TPbuyRange) && (element >= Convert.ToDouble(JsonResP.prices[0].closeoutBid)));
```

Which does not work as expected, it gives me always false.
And I modified to this, which works just fine, it gives me the boolean results as it should:

```
bool existsbuy1 = pricelist.Exists(element => (element <= TPbuyRange) );
bool existsbuy2 = pricelist.Exists(element => (element >= Convert.ToDouble(JsonResP.prices[0].closeoutBid)));
```

Then I have this one, which is very similar to the first line, and which works fine too:

```
bool existssell = pricelist.Exists(element => element >= TPsellRange & element <= Convert.ToDouble(JsonResP.prices[0].closeoutBid));
```

So I don't get it, what is wrong here?

Comment: You'll need to include some more information here. For example, what is `pricelist`? If it's a `List<something>` where `something` isn't a built-in .NET type, please provide the definition for `something`.

Comment: Also, `existsbuy1 && existsbuy2` isn't logically equivalent to `existsbuy`. `existsbuy` requires that a single element matches both conditions, whereas `existsbuy1` and `existsbuy2` can both be true even if different elements satisfy their individual conditions.

Comment: The first and second aren't the same - in the first an element has to be less than tpbuyrange and also simultaneously be greater than the closeout bid. In the second at least one element has to be less than the buy range and another potentially different element has to be greater than the closeoutbid

Comment: In the third one existsel1 - is that & on purpose, or did you copy && with a typing error?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
list = 10,20,30

list.Exists(e => e < 20 && e > 20); //false, no element is less than 20 and also greater than 20
```

Versus

```
list.Exists(e => e < 20); //true, element 10 is less than 20
list.Exists(e => e > 20); //true, element 30 is greater than 20
```

Your other one that works might be this:

```
list.Exists(e => e < 30 && e > 10); //true, element 20 is less than 30 and also greater than 10
```

Without knowing what your values are we can't say exactly but this will be the reason

---

I would also point out that because your Convert.ToDouble(...) is effectively a constant you should do it outside of the LINQ lambda

Comment: AS you can see the line contains "<=" and ">=" so it should include 20 in your example

Comment: You're missing the vital thing I'm trying to say. I'm making a point about mutually exclusive Boolean conditions. Read it as `e <= 19 && e >= 21` if you need to; this isn't about "greater than" vs "greater than or equal", this is about it being impossible for two particular things to be true at the same time, like `answer == "yes" && answer == "no"`

Comment: I see my logical mistake about the two separate lines existsbuy1 and  existsbuy2. But I still don't get it why the first line does not work, and what to do about it.... I have some values in the list . And I am trying to find out if any of them is in the range of the two values "TPbuyRange" and "Convert.ToDouble(JsonResP.prices[0].closeoutBid)" , those two will never have an identical value. So it should work I think....

Comment: It's not about them being identical values. I could have picked on an example that uses different values like `list.Exists(e => e < 11 && e > 29);` - these aren't identical values but there is still no value in the list that is simultaneously less than 11 and also greater than 29. **No number in the universe satisfies this**. Let's try and find one, starting with 1: `1 less than 11? TRUE. 1 less than 29? FALSE. TRUE && FALSE == FALSE`. Try 2: `2 less than 11? TRUE. 2 less than 29? FALSE. TRUE && FALSE == FALSE`. Keep going at it yourself trying to find a true; you'll still be trying next week!

Answer (score 0):

If the separate conditions both return true, that suggests that the list contains at least one item that satisfies the condition element <= TPbuyRange and at least one item that satisfies the condition element >= Convert.ToDouble(JsonResP.prices[0].closeoutBid)). However, if the joint condition does not return the same value as existsbuy1 && existsbuy2, that suggests that no item in the list satisfies both conditions at the same time.